# Limit of logarithm function, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log \left((n+1)!\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\log \left((n+1)!\right)}.$$
Now, I know that $\log x < \sqrt{x} < x$ and trying to apply comparison test, but it does not work. Please help.

Comment: Denominator is $\log ((n+1)!) or (\log (n+1))!$ ?

Comment: @Syuizen: Your second option doesn't make sense, as $\log(n+1)$ need not be an integer.

Comment: @voldemort, No. there exists the factorial of non integer numbers. $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$

Comment: @AlexSilva: I am aware of that. However, it seems extremely unlikely to be the case in this question- it's tagged calculus.

Comment: @Syuizen it means $\log ((n+1)!)$.

Comment: $\log(n+1)!=\log\{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)...3.2.1\}= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log(n-k)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$(n!)^2=\Bigl(1\cdot n\Bigr)\Bigl(2\cdot(n-1)\Bigr)\Bigl(3\cdot(n-2)\Bigr)\ldots\Bigl((n-1)\cdot 2\Bigr)\Bigl(n\cdot 1\Bigr)\ge n\cdot n\cdot\ldots\cdot n=n^n$$
(the graph of $x\cdot((n+1)-x)$ is a parabola oriented downwards)

Therefore (for $n\ge 2$)
$$0\le\frac{n}{\log((n+1)!)}\le\frac{n}{\log(n!)}=\frac{2n}{\log((n!)^2)}\le\frac{2n}{\log{n^n}}=\frac{2}{\log n}\to0$$
and the limit is $0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: good work done +1

Answer (score 5):

We have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\log(n+1)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\log 2+\log3+\ldots+\log(n+1)}.
$$
Since the logarithm is a monotone function, we can estimate the sum with integrals from below and above in the following way
$$
\int_1^{n+1}\log x\mathrm dx\le\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\log i\le\int_2^{n+2}\log x\mathrm dx.
$$
Also, we have that
$$
\int_1^{n+1}\log x\mathrm dx=(n+1)(\log(n+1)-1)+1
$$
and
$$
\int_2^{n+2}\log x\mathrm dx=(n+2)(\log(n+2)-1)-2(\log 2-1).
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\log i\sim n\log n
$$
as $n\to\infty$, where $\sim$ means that the ratio of the sequences tend to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. So the limit in question is $0$.

Comment: In this question, can I use L'Hopital's Law?

Comment: @nameless You would need to calculate the derivative of $\log(x+1)!$ and I'm not sure if it exists...

Comment: how is this estimation done in the second line?Please explain @V.C.

Comment: @learnmore $\int_1^{n+1}\log x\mathrm dx=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\int_{i-1}^i\log x\mathrm dx\le\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\log i$ since $\log(i-1)\le\log i$.

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's approximation $\log n!=O(n\log n)$.
Also $O((n+1)\log(n+1))=O(n\log n)$.

Therefore, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log((n+1)!)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}=0$$.